# AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering", false); not work for RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

When I set AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering", false); TextBox behaves normally, RichTextBox cannot display text. What is the reason for this result?

XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25"></Label>
        <TextBox Height="80" Width="500" Grid.Column="1" SelectionOpacity="1"></TextBox>

        <Label Content="RichTextBox" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25"></Label>
        <RichTextBox Height="80" Width="500" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" SelectionOpacity="1" Style="{StaticResource RichTextBoxStyle}"></RichTextBox>
       
    </Grid>
```

.Net6:

Codebedhind:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering", false);
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }
```

.NET Framework 4.8

App.config:

```
        <runtime>
            <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering=false"/>
        </runtime>
```

Is it possible to make the results of RichTextBox behave the same as the results of TextBox without changing the xaml code?

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the reason for this result?

The fact that the switch only applies to `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

> Is it possible to make the results of RichTextBox behave the same as the results of TextBox without changing the xaml code?

At least not using this, or any other, switch. Set the `SelectionOpacity` programmatically if you don't want to touch the XAML markup? If you can call the `AppContext.SetSwitch` method in the code-behind, you might as well also set a property of a control.

Comment: Hi,@mm8.I first want to verify if there is indeed no way to achieve that, while still keeping SelectionOpacity="1" and have a visible text in the RichTextBox?
According to your answer, I understand I can't use the UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering switch or any other switch for achieving that. Is there an alternative way to achieve this behaviour for the RichTextBox? Perhaps, it is possible to extend the RichTextBox with my own derived class, and override some method or default behavior?
If that is indeed not supported, I'll have to compromise & reduce the opacity as suggested by you.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to just "override" this behaviour in a derived class. Reducing the opacity programmatically is the easiest solution to your issue.